# switch / case request with boolean

Tags: java, android, boolean, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a method which checks if the Login (username and password) has a minimum of 6 charakters.

To realize that I created this method `public void checkLoginData(final String username, final String password)`. In that method, I create to booleans (user and pass), with those I can  create 4 different boolean-chains:

- user: true pass: true
- user: false pass: true
- user: false pass: false
- user: true pass: false

Now I'd like to do a switch/case request for each of them, but I don't get how to realize that...

If you ask why I need the switch, I just think I need it, because I'd like to do for every of those 4 boolean-chains, that it does/show something diffrent. Also I'd like to do this in a sexy-java-way not with tousands of diffrent 'ifs' :P, Please help!

Here's the code of the method:

```
public void checkLoginData(final String username, final String password){

    boolean user, pass;

    if (username.length() < 6){
        user = false;
    }else {
        user = true;
    }

    if (password.length() < 6){
        pass = false;
    }else {
        pass = true;
    }

    boolean[] logindaten = {user, pass};



}
```

---

Thx for the help in Advance!

Best Regards safari

Comment: What for do you need switch here? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I need for every of those boolean-chains that it does something diffrent. because of that i'd like to do this with a switch. But I don't get it working

Comment: Consider using an enum for each case to determine which current state you have instead of two doubles. So you can easily use switch/case then.

Comment: than post it as awnser, because I don't get what you mean, sorry

Comment: just added an example with using an enum.

Comment: yes saw it, I allready commented it, thx mate!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't switch over `boolean[]`, only over integral types. To convert the booleans to an int, you could use a bit mask for the 2 booleans, like for example this:

```
int val = 0;
if (user) val |= 0x1;
if (pass) val |= 0x2;

switch (val) {
case 0: // Both too short
case 1: // User Ok, pass too short
case 2: // User too short, pass ok
case 3: // Both Ok
}
```

Comment: Uggh ... anyone who thinks this is "sexy java" needs to go back to school.  You need to read it carefully to be sure that it is correct ... and that's always a bad sign.

Comment: Well, this is just a way how to do it with switch. I personally would implement it using an if / else if chain

Comment: @StephenC it may not be sexy but it is a fast and reliable way to do it... Granted, you could have used an enum, but this is even faster.

Comment: @fge - I don't think so.  This way executes 2 if tests and a switch plus two `|=` statements.  The simple way (nested ifs) is 2 if tests.  Besides, 99.9% of the time the performance difference is irrelevant.

Comment: just to complement: could use some constants instead of values, would improve readability

Comment: int means integer, not integral, and you can pass strings into switch statements

Answer (score 18):

If you really want a "sexy-java-way" (but that depends what you understand as such) you can do something like (Java 7 required):

```
boolean user, pass;

switch (user + "-" + pass) {
    case "false-false":
        ...
    case "false-true":
        ...
    case "true-false":
        ...
    case "true-true":
        ...
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "something strange happening here, user: " + user + ",pass: " + pass);
}
```

but I would prefer to do just 2 distinct checks each with his owns message, the message being joined for presentation. (and not sure if that could be considered "sexy-java-way", more like a 'workaround')

Comment: I think I understand why the bit mask is better but I think this method is much more readable and easier to update.

Comment: I get what you're trying to do but this is a bit of an antipattern in my opinion, casting a string out of a logical conclusion and then switching on that would be a code smell in any codebase that I'd work on. I'd prefer successive if statements by far.

Comment: @AlfredoGallegos have you read (understood) the whole answer? mainly the part "...I would prefer to do just 2 distinct checks..." - it is almost exactly the same you would prefer, isn't it? And the last sentence in parenthesis should be very clear of what I think about that solution... (almost 5 years ago...)

Comment: Yeah the OP wants to run different pieces of code for each possible boolean combination of user and pass. I know it's an old answer, but I think it's not the best of ideas to concatenate a string out of both booleans to use in a switch statement (which I'm also wary to use in OOP languages).

I mean, it does work, but it will not play nice with future refactors and we should try to push the OP (or whoever reads this in the future) to stick to more maintainable patterns. Somebody may see this in the future and it's going to end up in some application, and we should avoid that.

Comment: @AlfredoGallegos why do you repeat so much that is already wroten? Anyway, at least one person thought that this is easier to understand and maintain! The question was about a way to use `switch` instead of `if`, I presented one way... and clearly stated that it is not my preference, despite I eventually would use it, depending on the circunstances. Should I delete the answer - 11 upvotes, more than any other one here?

Comment: No, of course you don't need to delete :). The answer is worthy in its own way to showcase how to do things another way. The purpose of the discussion, though, is to make the point that even though it is an option, it's not the consensus.

Comment: Ugh, it is rather perverse than sexy... buuuut if the customer is happy => great :-D

To avoid misspelling and therefore improve the maintainability a bit I would propose to concatenate the boolean values on each case statement, like
case true + "-" + false: ...

Comment: @AleksandrKhomenko sure better. but no constant for `"-"`?,{hard to believe I wrote that answer, but it was 2012} [:-)

Answer (score 9):

Guess thats how I would solve it with enums:

```
public class LoginController
{
  private void login( String username, String password )
  {
    LoginState state = determineLoginState( username, password );

    switch ( state )
    {
      case LOGIN_OK:
        //Do Something
        break;
      case USERNAME_FALSE:
        //Do Something
        break;
      case PASSWORD_FALSE:
        //Do Something
        break;
      case BOTH_FALSE:
        //Do Something
        break;
    }

  }

  private LoginState determineLoginState( String username, String password )
  {
    final boolean checkUsername = checkUsername( username );
    final boolean checkPassword = checkPassword( password );

    if ( checkUsername && checkPassword )
      return LoginState.LOGIN_OK;

    if ( !checkUsername && checkPassword )
      return LoginState.USERNAME_FALSE;

    if ( checkUsername && !checkPassword )
      return LoginState.PASSWORD_FALSE;

    if ( !checkUsername && !checkPassword )
      return LoginState.BOTH_FALSE;

    throw new AuthenticationException();
  }

  protected boolean checkUsername( String username )
  {
    return username.length() > 6;
  }

  protected boolean checkPassword( String password )
  {
    return password.length() > 6;
  }

  private enum LoginState
  {
    LOGIN_OK, USERNAME_FALSE, PASSWORD_FALSE, BOTH_FALSE;
  }

  public class AuthenticationException extends RuntimeException
  {

  }
}
```

Comment: i did it an otherway. Thx for your help anyways!

Answer (score 8):

Basically there is no simpler way than this, and no way to do it in significantly less lines of code.

```
if (username.length() < 6){
    if (password.length() < 6){
        // do case 1
    } else {
        // do case 2
    }
} else {
    if (password.length() < 6){
        // do case 3
    } else {
        // do case 4
    }
}
```

To my mind, that makes this the best solution.

> Also I'd like to do this in a sexy-java-way not with tousands of diffrent 'ifs'

If by "sexy-java-way" you mean "clever" or "obscure", then there are other ways to do it.  But they certainly don't make the code easier to read / more maintainable.

By the way, the above involves only 3 ... that's right **THREE** ... `if` statements.

---

However your (final) specific example:

```
public void checkLoginData(final String username, final String password){
    boolean user, pass;
    if (username.length() < 6){
        user = false;
    }else {
        user = true;
    }
    if (password.length() < 6){
        pass = false;
    }else {
        pass = true;
    }
    boolean[] logindaten = {user, pass};
    ....
}
```

can be simplified to the following:

```
public void checkLoginData(final String username, final String password){
    boolean user = username.length() >= 6;
    boolean pass = password.length() >= 6;
    boolean[] logindaten = {user, pass};
    ....
}
```

Note that simplification is possible here because the actions (the "cases" in your hypothetical switch) can be refactored into simple boolean assignments AND the tests are actually independent of each other.  In general you can't do that ...

---

> ... but id like to have it more celver to impress my boss ;)

Seriously, if I was your boss and you wrote code like that, I'd be **UN-** impressed.  Any boss who thinks you are clever for writing obscure and unmaintainable code is clueless.

Comment: yes I know i had it exactly like this before, but id like to have it more celver to impress my boss ;) because I'm still learning all this java and android stuff! Anyway! Thx man! +1. Because of your funny comment :P

Answer (score 5):

```
if (user) {
    if (pass) {
        // user = true, pass = true
    } else {
        // user = true, pass = false
    }
} else {
    if (pass) {
        // user = false, pass = true
    } else {
        // user = false, pass = false
    }
}
```

Or

```
int case = user ? (pass ? 1 : 2) : (pass ? 3: 4);

switch (case) {  
  case 1:
    System.out.println(" user = true, pass = true ");
    break;
  case 2:
    System.out.println(" user = true, pass = false ");
    break;
  case 3:
    System.out.println(" user = false, pass = true ");
    break;
  case 4:
    System.out.println(" user = false, pass = false ");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: @safari If you have just 4 combinations, first one is fine. Tried the same using switch, check it out.

Comment: @4ndrew I just answered the question simply!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this and then each case is 1,2 or 3, etc.

```
switch((route.isComplete()?1:(route.getAuthentic()?2:(route.hasRoute()?3:0)))) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

With java12, you can use expressions within switch-case and provide a `Bool` type (https://blog.codefx.org/java/switch-expressions/).

Answer (score 0):

```java
private static boolean checkCharOf_(String userName){

  return userName.length() >= 6;

}

private static boolean checkCharOf_(String password){

  return password.length() >= 6;

}
```

or

```java
private static boolean checkCharOf_And_(String userName, String password){

  return userName.length() >= 6 && password.length() >= 6;

}
```

Comment: please try to always format your code using the buttons provided at the top of the editor. You can select the code then hit that button