# Switch case implementation in Java for an integer pair combination

Tags: java, python

I have following `python` code -

```
def get_subject_from_stream_id_and_subject_id(stream_id, subject_id):
#(stream_id, subject_id): ("subject_name")
return {
    (1, 1): "Accounts",
    (1, 2): "English",
    (1, 3): "Organization of Commerce",
    (2, 1): "Physics",
    (2, 2): "English",
    (2, 3): "Biology"
}.get((stream_id, subject_id), "None")
```

In this code, I want to get subject name from the integer pair combination i.e. `stream_id`, `subject_id` e.g. `(1, 2)` is for `English`. It was implemented using `python tuple`.

I want to implement the same piece of code in `Java`.

Could someone write this in a better way in `Java`?

```
public String getSubjectFromStreamIdAndSubjectId(int streamId, int subjectId) {
  switch (streamId) {
    case 1:
        switch (subjectId) {
        case 1:
            return "Accounts";
        case 2:
            return "English";
        case 3:
            return "Organization of Commerce";
        default:
            return null;
        }

    case 2:
        switch (subjectId) {
        case 1:
            return "Physics";
        case 2:
            return "English";
        case 3:
            return "Biology";
        default:
            return null;
        }
    default:
        return null;
   }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should post this here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: one other way is to use two arrays. If streamId == 1, use the first, if streamId == 2, get data from the second, and have subjectId match the index

Comment: This link has the solution for your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831061/switching-on-a-pair-of-ints

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching on a pair of \`int\`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831061/switching-on-a-pair-of-ints)

Comment: @gcdinesh could you comment which one could be the better implementation?

Comment: @Stultuske could u comment which one is a better implementation?

Comment: @deHaar could u comment which one is better implementation?

Comment: @EdgeGoldberg based on what would you consider one better over the other?

Comment: @Stultuske readable and/or time complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like the solution presented in the duplication suggestion [Switching on a pair of `int`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831061/switching-on-a-pair-of-ints). 
for two reasons:

1. The solution relies on external logic (`Integer.valueOf()` and switch of `String`) while it is not probable, the implementations may vary in future JDK releases
2. the switch-case was designed as shorthand for series of `if` statements. is not the best solution for mapping input to output values. A better solution is to utilize the `Map` data structure

The proper solution in my eyes would involve some kind Java `Tuple`. while there is no `Tuple` in the JDK, one can be easily constructed as user defined class. In fact, there is already an SO answer about that: [A Java collection of value pairs? (tuples?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521171/a-java-collection-of-value-pairs-tuples)
so if we use the class from the above-mentioned answer as Map key, the solution is fairly easy and much more extensible (you could, for instance, load the map from an external resource like text file or DB table):

```
// initialized using instance initializer
Map<Pair<Integer, Integer>, String> streamIdAndSubjectIdMap = new HashMap<>()
{
    {
        put(new Pair(1, 1), "Accounts");
        put(new Pair(1, 2), "English");
        put(new Pair(1, 3), "Organization of Commerce");
    }
};

public String getSubjectFromStreamIdAndSubjectId(int streamId, int subjectId) {
    return streamIdAndSubjectIdMap.get(new Pair<>(streamId, subjectId));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, i would really recommend to not use the `switch` statement here, since any hacks (like `String` concatenation) will just complicate things. However, you could refactor this method to use a regular `if` expression with a `return` statement.

```
public static String getSubject(int streamId, int subjectId) {
    Pair<Integer> pair = Pair.of(streamId, subjectId);

    if (pair.equals(Pair.of(1, 1))) {
        return "Subject";
    }
    if (pair.equals(Pair.of(1, 2))) {
        return "English";
    }
    if (pair.equals(Pair.of(1, 3))) {
        return "Organization of Commerce";
    }
    if (pair.equals(Pair.of(2, 1))) {
        return "Physics";
    }
    if (pair.equals(Pair.of(2, 2))) {
        return "English";
    }
    if (pair.equals(Pair.of(2, 3))) {
        return "Biology";
    }

    return null;
}
```

At least to my eye, this looks very clean and there is no need to use an `if-else` expression. One thing to note here is that the `Pair` class needs to be implemented correctly regarding `equals` and `hashCode` for this to work. An example implementation might be the following (tough it can still be extended):

```
public class Pair<T> {

    private T first;
    private T second;

    public static <T> Pair<T> of(T first, T second) {
        return new Pair<>(first, second);
    }

    private Pair(T first, T second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public T getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Pair<?> pair = (Pair<?>) o;
        return Objects.equals(first, pair.first) &&
                Objects.equals(second, pair.second);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(first, second);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not always recomended but in your case i would go with a nested ternary operator. If you have more combinations than given in your example this aproach could end in confusing, unreadable code. But if you have only those well defined cases:

```
public static String getSubjectFromStreamIdAndSubjectId(int stream_id, int subject_id) {
    return stream_id == 1 ?
            subject_id == 1 ? "Accounts" : 
            subject_id == 2 ? "English" : 
            subject_id == 3 ? "Organization of Commerce" : "None":
           stream_id == 2 ?
            subject_id == 1 ? "Physics" : 
            subject_id == 2 ? "English" : 
            subject_id == 3 ? "Biology" : "None":
           "None";
}
```